# Remove contents within a specific tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Using Rails 3.2. I want to remove all text in `<b>` and the tags, but I manage to find ways to strip the tags only.:

```
string = "
  <p>
    <b>Section 1</b>
    Everything is good.<br>
    <b>Section 2</b>
    All is well.
  </p>"
string.strip_tags
# => "Section 1 Everthing is good. Section 2 All is well."
```

I want to achieve this:

```
"Everthing is good. All is well."
```

Should I add regex matching too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "right" way would be to use an html parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org).
However for this simple task, you may use a regex. It's quite simple:
Search for : `(?m)<b\s*>.*?<\/b\s*>` and replace it with empty string. After that, use `strip_tags`.

**Regex explanation:**

```
(?m)    # set the m modifier to match newlines with dots .
<b      # match <b
\s*     # match a whitespace zero or more times
>       # match >
.*?     # match anything ungreedy until </b found
<\/b    # match </b
\s*     # match a whitespace zero or more times
>       # match >
```

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://rubular.com/r/7y9faY3WJj)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

It would be much better to use an HTML/XML parser for this task.  Ruby does not have a native one, but [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/) is good and wraps libxml/xslt

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML string
doc.xpath("//b").remove
result = doc.text # or .inner_html to include `<p>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `string.gsub(/<b>.*<\/b>/, '')`

http://rubular.com/r/hhmpY6Q6fX

Comment: Adding `{1}` is always useless.

Comment: Ok ..not required ..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove tags you can try this :

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("test<br>test<br>test<br> test")
```

if you want to remove all the tags you need to use this :

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize("test<br>test<br>test<br> test")
```

these two differ slightly.the first one is good for script tags to prevent Xss attacks but it doesn't remove tages. the second one removes any html tags in the text.